# Enabling FILESTREAM for SQL Server 2022 in a Windows Docker Container

Tags: sql-server, docker, powershell, containers, sqlfilestream

**Problem:**

I'm trying to enable FILESTREAM for SQL Server 2022 running inside a Docker container, but I'm encountering issues. Since I am using SQL Server 2022 in a container, I don't have access to SQL Server Configuration Manager. As a result, I need to find an alternative way to enable FILESTREAM.

For context, I installed SQL Server 2022 Developer Edition in a Server Core 2019 container (Windows Container). I am now trying to enable FILESTREAM on SQL Server 2022 running in a windows container. Even using a Windows container, I still continue to have trouble enabling FILESTREAM.

If anyone has any advice on how to correctly enable FILESTREAM for SQL Server 2022 in a Windows Docker container, it would be greatly appreciated.

**What I've Tried:**

I've tried to enable FILESTREAM several different ways including:

1. Powershell.
2. Configuring a config file (.ini) for headless SQL Server installs.
3. Using SQL Server Management Studio.

No matter what I do, whenever I try to restore a FILESTREAM database I receive an error saying "FILESTREAM feature is not enabled".

Comment: You can't enable it. Filestream is not supported on SQL Server on Linux.

Comment: As for SQL Server running in a *Windows* container, this deployment is *not* supported. Microsoft [abandoned](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/update-beta-program-for-sql-server-on-windows-container-is/ba-p/2516639) that avenue many years ago, after not giving the project any attention for [around 3 years](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/update-beta-program-for-sql-server-on-windows-container-is/bc-p/2519126/highlight/true#M1762).

Comment: @ThomA I found a way to create my own windows server core image with SQL Server 2022. Would a windows container also no support FILESTREAM?

Comment: I wouldn't like to comment, as (as mentioned) the deployment method isn't supported; what can or can't work isn't documented.